# Escape string characters without manually escaping them

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

I Need to replace a set of characters from a string, I don't have control over the string so I can't just escape the `+` symbol inside the string.

So my question is, seeing as this works if I change my value to 'breeding' it does replace the string. How can I escape a string without manually escaping them? I have tried

```
var s = "http://example.co/kb/tags/anazolic~racing~all+articles~breeding";
var value = 'all+articles';

var find = new RegExp('\~?\\b' + value + '\\b', 'g');
var l = s.replace(find, '');
console.log(l);
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/AnBc6/1/

I have also tried adding: `value = encodeURIComponent(value);` but this didn't work either.

Any Help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape regular expression in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to escape special regex characters.

```
value = value.replace(/[-\\()\[\]{}^$*+.?|]/g, '\\$&');
```

You could extract this to a function of course:

```
function escapeRegex(value) {
    return String(value).replace(/[-\\()\[\]{}^$*+.?|]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

Comment: In that case, this is a duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Change the third line to this:

```
var find = new RegExp('\~?\\b' + value.replace(/\+/g,'\\+') + '\\b', 'g');
```

The plus sign is a special character in a Regular Expression, so it needs to be escaped with a backslash.

(Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "stored in a variable."  Everything in JavaScript is "in a variable."  Or maybe you really mean, "stored in a RegExp object.")

Comment: Well, I meant I don't manually type in the string, it's automatically generated, sorry about tht